# How can I seamlessly send a file to another app?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to add a moderately large (200 kB to 4+ MB) file to what I'm sending to another app. The apps are from different organizations, but I can ask the developers of the other app to implement what I need. I need something that works on both Android and iOS within the Xamarin.Forms framework, although if it requires separate implementations on the two platforms that’s fine.

My current method is to use an app url to launch the other app, with a query string that has a base64-encoded representation of the data. However, the size limit that Xamarin places on URIs (65 kB) is a lot smaller than the size of the additional file.

Other desired features:

- The hand-off should be seamless. I don’t want any permissions or sharing or file picker dialogs to show up, except maybe the first time they do it.
- It should work without an internet connection. I’ve considered uploading the file to the cloud and then having the other app download it, but I want this to work without an internet connection.

Solutions I've looked into:

- Pasteboards on iOS - no longer allowed for apps from different organizations.
- File sharing, like with Xamarin.Essentials.Share - it would work, but unless there's a way to skip through the share dialog it isn't as seamless as I'd like.
- Saving the file to a public location like the downloads folder and then having the other app retrieve and delete it from there - as I understand it, this requires the user to interact with a file picker dialog every time on iOS. Is that correct?
- Cloud upload/download - it would work, but people might switch from my app to theirs before they have internet connection and then not switch back once they're connected.

Comment: I don't think there is a great *seamless* solution for this that wouldn't run into sandbox restrictions.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Apple in particular seems to have shut down a lot of ways that apps could secretly communicate with each other. Understandable, but inconvenient.

Comment: Save the file where you want. Then on Android use FileProvider to build an uri. Start the other app with the uri in the querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, you can make use of the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing), and just pass the location of the file through in a query string for the "receiving" application to deal with.

As you've identified though, iOS is much more tricky. Honestly, the end result will probably be that the sync is less seamless on Apple devices. Consumers are, in some ways, trained for this behaviour already. On Android, Spotify will let you download all your music in the background, on iOS, the app has to be in the foreground.

iOS is just not geared towards allowing apps from two different companies to communicate with each other on device. There's just too many vectors of abuse.

You seem to have researched enough of the options. There's no reliable way to skip the share dialog in iOS, so if that's really a killer for you, then the cloud upload / download is going to be your best bet. You'll have connectivity edge cases that you'll need to deal with though - as you've already identified.